# kill-this-buffer doesn't work in all buffers yet the emacs menu "close" does, what's the difference?

Tags: key-bindings

I have the command `kill-this-buffer` bound to `C-x C-x`. yet it seems it doesn't work in all buffers (such as the calendar month view etc. yet the emacs menu `close` always does work. whats the difference between the two (the menu `close` doesn't seem to have a keybind) and how does one bind it to a key?

Comment: Might not be a good idea to bind `C-x C-x` to `kill-buffer`, which is by default bound  to `exchange-point-and-mark` which is a very useful function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In whatever buffer your keyboard shortcut does not work as expected, type `C-h k` or `M-x describe-key` and then your keyboard shortcut to see what function it is actually bound to -- major-modes and minor-modes can override global key bindings.

For example, in the `*Calendar*` buffer type `C-h k C-x C-x` and see that it is bound to `calendar-exchange-point-and-mark`, which is defined in the `calendar-mode-map`.

Some people like a global minor-mode for custom keybindings, whereas others may chose to unset / remove major-mode and minor-mode bindings that conflict with global-bindings.  And others may choose to assign additional major-mode / minor-mode bindings for certain functions.

Answer (score 1):

The menu bar's `close` invokes `kill-this-buffer`. The problem, as [@lawlist describes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30545/10269), is that your global `C-x C-x` binding is being overwritten by `calendar-mode`.

`C-c <letter>` key sequences are [reserved for the user](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Mode-Conventions.html), so try a global binding such as `C-c k` instead.

Also note that `kill-this-buffer` is part of the `menu-bar` package (written long before the convention that all symbols of a package need to be prefixed by the package name was strictly enforced). The code is as below:

```el
(defun kill-this-buffer ()  ; for the menu bar
  "Kill the current buffer.
When called in the minibuffer, get out of the minibuffer
using `abort-recursive-edit'."
  (interactive)
  (cond
   ;; Don't do anything when `menu-frame' is not alive or visible
   ;; (Bug#8184).
   ((not (menu-bar-menu-frame-live-and-visible-p)))
   ((menu-bar-non-minibuffer-window-p)
    (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
   (t
    (abort-recursive-edit))))
```

I've experienced issues with it not working sometimes (presumably when `(not (menu-bar-menu-frame-live-and-visible-p))`), so I just bind `C-c k` to `(lambda () (interactive) (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))`.

Comment: Because `kill-this-buffer` might silently do nothing, you can use `kill-current-buffer` (emacs 26.3).